# TestNG accessing the ISuite in @BeforeSuite

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to access ISuite when running a suite for setting attributes that will be needed by every test.

Following is the code:

public class SingleTester{

```
IAttributes attributes;

@BeforeSuite
public void setup(ISuite suite)
{
    attributes = suite;
    attributes.setAttribute("test", "car");
    createAccount();
}
....
```

The problem is test fails with the following message:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method setup requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.
```

What is wrong? How can I access the ISuite object from the @BeforeSuite function?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it shoud be ITestContext, not ISuite.

```
@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite(ITestContext context)
{
    context.getSuite().setAttribute("name", "value");
}
```

Comment: ITestContext is created on each test, what i need is a context that lives across multiple tests.